# How pairing is done between Single Mode and Dual Mode in Bluetooth LE

Tags: bluetooth

I am Understanding blueooth LE and in the that i am currently looking into pairing between the devices. I have understood the pairing between Single Mode device. But I am not getting how pairing is done between single and dual mode. I have googled but couldnt get any content. can you please tell me how it is implemented and if URL's are given then that would be much more useful

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have single mode LE device and a dual-mode BR/EDR and LE device then they can only connect and pair using an LE connection using LE Security (see the Bluetooth Specification (Core Spec v 4.0) [Vol 3] Part H, 3.6 Security in Bluetooth Low Energey - Available from www.bluetooth.org - login required).

If you have two dual mode devices then they must connect and pair over BR/EDR even when using GATT and LE profiles, under the current 4.0 specification.

There are changes for the 4.1 version (not yet ratified) that will change that restriction.

Comment: Hi,So you mean to say that the pairing between a device with EDR and a device with LE will have the same pairing sequences as given in the Bluetooth Specification (Core Spec v 4.0) [Vol 3] Part H, 5- Appentices 5.3 MESSAGE SEQUENCE CHARTS

Comment: Yes, I believe that is the case.

Comment: Additional Information: I believe the part of the specification that dictates dual-mode devices must use BR/EDR transport even when using GATT is Bluetooth Specification 4.0 [VOL 3] Part C - Generic Access Profile, Section 2.6 - Other Requirements.